# Kafka - Optimal ec2 machine type for processing 100 messages / second

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am going to setup Amazon ec2 instance for kafka and I am going to process about 100 messages / second (7 days retention).

For now I will start with single machine (broker). I want to know that what type of ec2 is suitable for my case.

Is 4CPUs and 8GB RAM (c5.xlarge) good to start?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [Link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html). This link contains the basic details about the server, disk, filesystem exact JVM options required to setup Kafka on production.

Refer these links to optimise  throughput :

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-apache-kafka-deployment/
- https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_performance.html